# How To assign priority to mongodb 3.2 replica?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-shell

I have mongodb database with replication(1 primary and 4 secondary machine named as node1, node2,node3, node4 and node5 ). I want to assign priority to nodes. If `node1` goes down then `node2` should become primary If `node1` and `node2` goes down then `node3` should become primary and so on.
I am trying to assign priority Using below command but it is not changing:

```
cfg = rs.conf()
cfg.members[0].priority = 20
cfg.members[1].priority = 15
cfg.members[2].priority = 10
cfg.members[3].priority = 5
cfg.members[4].priority = 1
rs.reconfig(cfg)
```

I am using Mongodb version: 3.2

Comment: `rs.reconfig(cfg)` should have thrown an error "errmsg" : "priority must be 0 when non-voting (votes:0)". Had the same issue and accepted answer works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to configure [votes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/replica-configuration/#rsconf.members[n].votes) also.

```
cfg = rs.conf()
cfg.members[0].votes = 1;
cfg.members[0].priority = 20;
cfg.members[1].votes = 1;
cfg.members[1].priority = 15;
cfg.members[2].votes = 1;
cfg.members[2].priority = 10;
cfg.members[3].votes = 1
cfg.members[3].priority = 5;
cfg.members[4].votes = 1
cfg.members[4].priority = 1;
rs.reconfig(cfg);
```

> IMPORTANT Changed in version 3.2:
>
> Non-voting members must have
>
> priority of 0. Members with priority greater than 0 cannot have 0
>   votes.
>
> To configure a member as non-voting, set both its votes and priority values to 0.

Refer [MongoDB Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-a-non-voting-replica-set-member/) for more info about [votes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/replica-configuration/#rsconf.members[n].votes) and [priority](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/replica-configuration/#rsconf.members[n].priority).